# Why are "use" statements not working in my PHP scripts?

Tags: php

I'm coming back to PHP after many years and am running into a bit of an odd problem. I'm running PHP 7.1.7 on Windows and am trying to install and utilize the [maclof/kubernetes-client library](https://github.com/maclof/kubernetes-client) via Composer. I have the following simple code snippet to test things out:

```php
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Maclof\Kubernetes\Client;

$path = realpath(__DIR__ . '/kubeconfig.yaml');

// this works (when fully qualified)
$config = Maclof\Kubernetes\Client::parseKubeconfigFile($path);

// but this doesn't
$client = new Client($config);

?>
```

As you can see, when I access the static method `parseKubeconfigFile` using the fully-qualified class name (`Maclof\Kubernetes\Client`), this works. But when I try to just use the shorter name of `Client`, it doesn't work. Even `class_exists("Client")` returns false. It's as though PHP is outright ignoring the `use` statement, and I don't know why.

What am I missing? Is there some weird php.ini directive that governs `use` statements? Or is there some wacky bug in this specific version of PHP? I'm pulling my hair out right now trying to understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: Please share the error message. 'It doesn't work' is usually not helpful. `class_exists` ignores short names.

Comment: It simply doesn't run. I've been testing this by putting echo statements around them, and it dies as soon as it hits the line initializing the $client. I've been checking in Event Viewer for more detailed logs but nothing's showing up there.

Comment: Then your first step is to figure out how to enable error messages in PHP.

Comment: If I call `syslog(LOG_INFO, "test");` that DOES show up in Event Viewer. So clearly logs are being routed there. I just don't see any errors there in this case.

Comment: Configuring PHP to emit error messages, warnings, etc. is a pretty common task, but it may be off by default. There should be enough keywords here to google how to do this. Good luck!